# Mysql 8.0 using low CPU/RAM and slow Queries

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I just upgrade my server to

AMD EPYC 16 Cores
CPU AMD EPYC 7282 16 x 2.80 GHz
RAM 256 GB REG ECC
2 TB SSD

The issue is, I'm using the WordPress plugin "Query Monitor" and each time I'm getting alert "Query Slow"

Example SQL WordPress

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR( post_date ) AS year, MONTH( post_date ) AS month
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Execute Time: 0.1125

I'm using Webmin and the CPU is not going more than 10% most of time is staying 2%/5% and Memory Ram is 9% or 11% only ...
The Mysql is not using many resources and I'm not sure how to tune it so MySQL query will be faster ... i found this my.cfg config I make some changes but still can't succeed to make the queries faster

```
# === Optimized my.cnf configuration for MySQL/MariaSQL (on Ubuntu, CentOS etc. servers) ===
#
# by Fotis Evangelou, developer of Engintron (engintron.com)
#
# ~ Updated February 2021 ~
#
#
# The settings provided below are a starting point for a 8-16 GB RAM server with 4-8 CPU cores.
# If you have different resources available you should adjust accordingly to save CPU, RAM & disk I/O usage.
#
# The settings marked with a specific comment or the word "UPD" (after the value)
# should be adjusted for your system by using database diagnostics tools like:
#
# https://gist.github.com/fevangelou/fb72f36bbe333e059b66
# or
# https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl
# or
# https://github.com/RootService/tuning-primer (supports MySQL up to v5.7)
#
# Run either of these scripts before optimizing your database, at least 1 hr after the optimization & finally
# at least once a day for 3 days (without restarting the database) to see how your server performs and if you need
# to re-adjust anything. The more MySQL/MariaDB runs without restarting, the more usage data it gathers, so these
# diagnostics scripts will report in mode detail how MySQL/MariaDB performs.
#
#
# IMPORTANT NOTE: If there is NO comment after a setting value, then 99,9% of the times you won't need to adjust it.
#
#
# --- THINGS TO DO AFTER YOU UPDATE MY.CNF - TROUBLESHOOTING ---
#
# If any terminal commands are mentioned, make sure you execute them as "root" user.
#
# If MySQL or MariaDB cannot start (or restart), then perform the following actions.
#
# 1. If the server had the stock database configuration and you added or updated any
#    "innodb_log_*" settings (as suggested below), then execute these commands ONLY
#    the first time you apply this configuration:
#
#    $ rm -rvf /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*
#    $ chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
#    $ service mysql restart
#
#    or use the shorthand command:
#    $ rm -rvf /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*; chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql; service mysql restart
#
# 2. If the setting "bind-address" is not commented out, then make sure the file /etc/hosts is
#    properly configured. A good example of a "clean" /etc/hosts file is something like this:
#
#    127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
#    ::1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
#    1.2.3.4   hostname.domain.tld hostname # <-- Replace accordingly!
#
#    Finally restart the database service:
#
#    $ service mysql restart
#
# 3. If the database service cannot restart even after the first 2 steps, make sure the database data folder
#    (common for either MySQL or MariaDB) "/var/lib/mysql" is owned by the "mysql" user AND group.
#    Additionally, the folder itself can have 0751 or 0755 file permissions. To fix it, simply do this:
#    $ chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
#    $ chmod 0755 /var/lib/mysql
#
#    Finally restart the database service:
#
#    $ service mysql restart
#
#
# ~ FIN ~


[mysql]
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
# === Required Settings ===
basedir                         = /usr
bind_address                    = 127.0.0.1 # Change to 0.0.0.0 to allow remote connections
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
max_allowed_packet              = 256M
max_connect_errors              = 1000000
#pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
port                            = 3306
skip_external_locking
skip_name_resolve
disable_log_bin
general_log                     = OFF
#socket                          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
tmpdir                          = /tmp
user                            = mysql

# === SQL Compatibility Mode ===
# Enable for b/c with databases created in older MySQL/MariaDB versions
# (e.g. when using null dates)
#sql_mode                       = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

# === InnoDB Settings ===
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 128     # Use 1 instance per 1GB of InnoDB pool size
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 210G    # Use up to 70-80% of RAM
innodb_file_per_table           = ON
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 16M
innodb_log_file_size            = 1G
innodb_stats_on_metadata        = 0

#innodb_temp_data_file_path     = ibtmp1:64M:autoextend:max:20G # Control the maximum size for the ibtmp1 file
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 0     # Optional: Set to the number of CPUs on your system (minus 1 or 2) to better
                                        # contain CPU usage. E.g. if your system has 8 CPUs, try 6 or 7 and check
                                        # the overall load produced by MySQL/MariaDB.
innodb_read_io_threads          = 64
innodb_write_io_threads         = 64
#innodb_io_capacity             = 1000  # Max is 2000

# === MyISAM Settings ===
# The following 3 options are ONLY supported by MariaDB & up to MySQL 5.7
# Do NOT un-comment on MySQL 8.x+
#query_cache_limit              = 4M    # UPD
#query_cache_size               = 64M   # UPD
#query_cache_type               = 1     # Enabled by default

key_buffer_size                 = 32M   # UPD

low_priority_updates            = 1
concurrent_insert               = 2

# === Connection Settings ===
max_connections                 = 10000   # UPD - Important: high no. of connections = high RAM consumption

back_log                        = 512
thread_cache_size               = 100
thread_stack                    = 192K

interactive_timeout             = 180
wait_timeout                    = 180

# For MySQL 5.7+ only (disabled by default)
#max_execution_time             = 30000 # Set a timeout limit for SELECT statements (value in milliseconds).
                                        # This option may be useful to address aggressive crawling on large sites,
                                        # but it can also cause issues (e.g. with backups). So use with extreme caution and test!
                                        # More info at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time

# For MariaDB 10.1.1+ only (disabled by default)
#max_statement_time             = 30    # The equivalent of "max_execution_time" in MySQL 5.7+ (set above)
                                        # The variable is of type double, thus you can use subsecond timeout.
                                        # For example you can use value 0.01 for 10 milliseconds timeout.
                                        # More info at: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aborting-statements/

# === Buffer Settings ===
innodb_sort_buffer_size         = 180000M    # UPD
join_buffer_size                = 96M    # UPD
read_buffer_size                = 96M    # UPD
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 96M    # UPD
sort_buffer_size                = 96M    # UPD

# === Table Settings ===
# In systemd managed systems like Ubuntu 16.04+ or CentOS 7+, you need to perform an extra action for table_open_cache & open_files_limit
# to be overriden (also see comment next to open_files_limit).
# E.g. for MySQL 5.7, please check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-systemd.html
# and for MariaDB check: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
table_definition_cache          = 40000 # UPD
table_open_cache                = 40000 # UPD
open_files_limit                = 60000 # UPD - This can be 2x to 3x the table_open_cache value or match the system's
                                        # open files limit usually set in /etc/sysctl.conf or /etc/security/limits.conf
                                        # In systemd managed systems this limit must also be set in:
                                        # /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.d/override.conf (for MySQL 5.7+) and
                                        # /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.conf (for MariaDB)

max_heap_table_size             = 1000M
tmp_table_size                  = 1000M

# === Search Settings ===
ft_min_word_len                 = 3     # Minimum length of words to be indexed for search results

# === Logging ===
log_error                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes   = 1
long_query_time                 = 5
slow_query_log                  = 0     # Disabled for production
slow_query_log_file             = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_slow.log

[mysqldump]
# Variable reference
# For MySQL 5.7+:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html
# For MariaDB:     https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqldump/
quick
quote_names
max_allowed_packet              = 512M
```

wp_posts has 76439 Rows Type InnoDB

Each time I'm trying to access a link that is not cached and is reading from Mysql is slow loading the page, and should not be ... the CPU is still only 2% used most time ...

Comment: Your configuration may be fine but the query might have issues. What would help is to pre-pend EXPLAIN on the above query and post the output here.

Comment: the query is from WordPress, is default query how WordPress is showing the posts on the page, didn't make any changes on the script part

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) STATUS; not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS; G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; AND Optional very helpful, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, ulimit -a for a Linux/Unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Speed up *that* query by adding this index to `wp_posts`:

```
INDEX(post_type, attachment)
```

The query will have to scan all 76439 rows in the index, but that index will be smaller than `wp_posts`, itself.

I expect `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 210G` will be more than adequate.

These are going the wrong direction for monitoring performance:

```
long_query_time                 = 5
slow_query_log                  = 0     # Disabled for production
```

"5" would not have caught the "0.1125".  I recommend "1".  And keep the slowlog on, even on production.  There are more settings that need checking:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog